# Best way to block images in email rendered in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, image, html-email, email-client

I've created a simple web email client.

I want to "block" (i.e. not show) images whose protocol is http (vs https) because my site is served over ssl and I don't want insecure content warnings.

What's the best way to go about this? Should I traverse the email dom and set the image href to "" (ie. empty string)?

Is there a better way?

I should note that this is a temporary measure. In the future I will set up an image proxy/cache system similar to gmail's.

Comment: On the serverside, remove the href attributes....

Comment: Hi @epascarello So you would also suggest removing the hrefs as the best way to "block" the images?

Comment: There is nothing on the clientside that can stop the browser from requesting them so you need to do it on the server. Set them as data-href, set the href to some placeholder or nothing at all. And if the user wants to view the images, than simply swap the data-href for the href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the way it's done in Outlook, gmail, yahoo, etc. Basically they just use a placeholder image (hosted on some cdn) that's just a small grey box, and they let the size attributes of the img tag scale it to the right size.

So all they do is change the url of the img tag to be the url of the grey box.

A smart variation if you want to eventually show the correct image (enable images) is to store the url of the real image location as part of a query string that can be parsed and used later to get the real image:

http://mycdn.com/placeholderimage.jpg?http://realcdn.com/therealimage.jpg